# Tracking Javascript keyboard event in a player object constructor

Tags: javascript

I’m doing a simple JS 2D board game for learning purposes. And I’m having trouble making sure that the player’s movements which are kicked off  by arrow-keyboard-inputs get properly tracked in the console.

Supposing, I just want to limit myself to tracking any movement using the left arrow key:

then below there is the corresponding constructor function used for pre-defining the player objects that make their moves on the board (as I said, only to the left, for the time being:

```js
function Player(name, posY, posX, currentTurn, numberMoves, weapon, previousWeapon) {

  this.name = name;

  this.posY = posY;

  this.posX = posX;

  this.currentTurn = currentTurn;

  this.numberMoves = numberMoves; // counting the number of moves player has made.

  this.weapon = weapon;

  this.locatePosition = function() {

    var l = 0;

    var m = 0;



    for (l = 0; l < mapArray.length; l++) {

      for (m = 0; m < mapArray.length; m++) {



        if ((mapArray[l][m]) === this.number) {

          this.posY = [l];

          this.posX = [m];

          console.log("Player Position Y: " + this.posY + " + position X: " + this.posX);

        }

      }

    }

  }

  //

  this.movement = function() {

    document.onkeydown = (e) => {

      switch (e.which) {

        case 37: // left - 1

          this.numberMoves += 1;

          console.log("player's number of moves made:" + this.numberMoves);

          this.posX = parseInt((this.posX) - 1);

          this.newPosY = this.posY;

          this.newPosX = this.posX;

          console.log("new position: " + this.newPosY + ", " + this.newPosX);

          break;
      }
    }

  };

}
```

Later, however, when an object is created and I try to move it on the board using the left-key, I get this console.message:

new position: undefined, NaN

Why?

For the complete code of this work in progress:

```js
// * / constructor function pre-defining the player objects

function Player(name, posY, posX, currentTurn, numberMoves, weapon, previousWeapon) {
  this.name = name;
  this.posY = posY;
  this.posX = posX;
  this.currentTurn = currentTurn;
  this.numberMoves = numberMoves;
  this.weapon = weapon;
  this.locatePosition = function() {
    var l = 0;
    var m = 0;

    for (l = 0; l < mapArray.length; l++) {
      for (m = 0; m < mapArray.length; m++) {

        if ((mapArray[l][m]) === this.number) {
          this.posY = [l];
          this.posX = [m];
          console.log("Player Position Y: " + this.posY + " + position X: " + this.posX);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //
  this.movement = function() {
    document.onkeydown = (e) => {
      switch (e.which) {
        case 37: // left - 1
          this.numberMoves += 1;
          console.log("player's number of moves made:" + this.numberMoves);
          this.posX = parseInt((this.posX) - 1);
          this.newPosY = this.posY;
          this.newPosX = this.posX;
          console.log("new position: " + this.newPosY + ", " + this.newPosX);
          break;
      }

    }
  };

}

// * creating two Player Objects
var player1 = new Player("Red Sonja");
var player2 = new Player("Robin");

// array that will be useful for a function that answers the question: "Whose turn is it?": determineInitialTurn
var turnArray = [player1, player2];

//* function that picks a random element of an array, a function we use in determineInitialTurn
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
};

function determineInitialTurn() {
  shuffleArray(turnArray);
  turnArray[0].currentTurn = true; // this player will have the first turn.
  turnArray[1].currentTurn = false;
  console.log("Is it " + (turnArray[0].name) + "'s turn? :" + turnArray[0].currentTurn);
};
//constructor for weapon objects
function Weapon(name, posY, posX, force) {

  this.name = name;
  this.posY = posY;
  this.posX = posX;
  this.force = force;
  this.locatePositionWeapon = function() {
    var l = 0;
    var m = 0;
    for (l = 0; l < mapArray.length; l++) {
      for (m = 0; m < mapArray.length; m++) {
        if ((mapArray[l][m]) === 6) {
          this.posY = [l];
          this.posX = [m];
          console.log(this.position + " posY: " + this.posY + " + posX: " + this.posX);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
// we create 4 weapon objects
var weapon1 = new Weapon("Tank", 10);
var weapon2 = new Weapon("Molotov", 8);
var weapon3 = new Weapon("Gun", 6);
var weapon4 = new Weapon("Bomb", 14);

// simple array where the weapons are listed. needed later in defining movement function.
var weapons = [weapon1, weapon2, weapon3, weapon4];


/*
bi-dimensional array with an initial distribution of elements.
Each number stands for an element in the game:
0 - empty
1 - rocktexture
 */

var mapArray = [ // bi-dimensional array with an initial distribution of elements (each number stands for an element in the game ()
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, weapon1, 0, player1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, weapon2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, weapon3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, player2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, weapon4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];


// function that allows to shuffle the initial distribution of elements to create a random map.
function shuffleMap() {

  function fisherYates(myArray) {
    var i = myArray.length,
      j, tempi, tempj;
    if (i === 0) return false;
    while (--i) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      tempi = myArray[i];
      tempj = myArray[j];
      myArray[i] = tempj;
      myArray[j] = tempi;
    }
  }

  mapArray.forEach(fisherYates);
};

// for each number in the array there is a div and we drap the map accordingly.
function drawMap() {

  for (v = 0; v < mapArray.length; v++) {
    for (w = 0; w < mapArray.length; w++) {

      switch ((mapArray[v][w])) {

        case weapon1:
          $('#container').append('<div class="weapon1"></div>');
          break;
        case weapon2:
          $('#container').append('<div class="weapon2"></div>');
          break;
        case weapon3:
          $('#container').append('<div class="weapon3"></div>');
          break;
        case weapon4:
          $('#container').append('<div class="weapon4"></div>');
          break;
        case player1:
          $('#container').append('<div class="player1"></div>');
          break;
        case player2:
          $('#container').append('<div class="player2"></div>');
          break;
        case 0:
          $('#container').append('<div class="empty"></div>');
          break;
        case 1:
          $('#container').append('<div class="rock"></div>');;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
};

// the program

$('document').ready(function() {
  shuffleMap();
  drawMap();
  determineInitialTurn();
  player1.locatePosition();
  player2.locatePosition();
  player1.movement();
  player2.movement();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 40em;
  height: 40em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.empty {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

.rock {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("http://img.hb.aicdn.com/91fd74edefe009c9058249832093409b505306dd65e1-h1FZVz_fw658");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4em;
}

.weapon1 {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/544/544497.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4em;
  z-index: 90;
}

.weapon2 {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/544/544497.svg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4em;
  z-index: 90;
}

.weapon3 {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/544/544497.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4em;
  z-index: 90;
}

.weapon4 {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/544/544497.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4em;
  z-index: 90;
}

.player1 {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/many-people-flat-icons/128/wonder-women-512.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4em;
  z-index: 100;
}

.player2 {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/many-people-flat-icons/128/superman-128.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4em;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Boarderino</title>
  <meta name="description" content="a simple JS board-game">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you cannot understand your spaghetti, how should we do? You should narrow your question down to the place where the problem is, try to debug all the values that are coming into those place and you solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of `this.posX`, `this.posY`, `this.numberMoves`, `this.weapon` are never given a value. True, they are assigned a value in the `Person` constructor, but you don't pass the arguments, so they will still be `undefined`.

You'll get something when doing:

```
var player1 = new Player("Red Sonja", 0, 0, false, 0);
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...etc.

There is a lot more that should be changed/fixed in your code, but it is too much to list. Just a few things:

- A function `locatePosition` seems useless when you already have `posX`, `posY`. It is a waste of time to look for the item in the whole array, when you know where it is by its coordinates.
- In a turn-based game, the number of moves made should not be stored for each player separately, but only once. It is common to store the "ply" number instead of the move number, i.e. the count of separate moves: 0 means player1 is to move, 1 means player2 is to move, 2 means player 1 is to move, ...etc.
- Similarly, you should not store the fact whether it's a player's turn in its own properties. This should either be a separate variable, and only one, or even better be just derived from the ply-number (`ply % 2`).
- In constructors you should not accept that many arguments. It is not practical, and often not necessary either. Instead, give default values for some of the properties.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the tracking I wanted now. You are right on all the other points, too...

Comment: I won't bug you any further, except for this: do you have any idea why the drawMap function that is looping over the map array does not append a div for all the elements of the array? At some point the iteration stops...

Comment: Your inner `for` has a mistake. It should not iterate up to `mapArray.length`, but to `mapArray[v].length`. You could also reduce that `switch` to an `if` and reuse the `.name` property of a weapon object (if it is a Weapon object). That makes your code more generic (imagine you would add a fifth weapon). In fact, you should not store weapons in separate variables, but in an array only...

Comment: Thank you again! your advice is very precious :-)

Comment: Glad it is of use to you ;-)